# Should I set `inter_op_parallelism_threads` and `intra_op_parallelism_threads` to 1 when I use ray to create a actor?

Tags: python, tensorflow, ray

When I use ray to create the actors and learner in A2C, should I set `inter_op_parallelism_threads` and `intra_op_parallelism_threads` to `1`, or leave it by default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends how many resources you want to the actor to use. If there is a dedicated machine for a given actor, and it's ok for the actor to use all of the resources on that machine, then use TensorFlow's default settings. If you are creating more like one actor per core, then setting `inter_op_parallelism_threads` and `intra_op_parallelism_threads` to small values like 1 or 2 is a good idea.

In general, you can try both approaches and see which is faster.

Comment: Thanks, so if I create an actor per core, then both should be set to 1?

Comment: Yes, though it's worth trying setting `inter_op_parallelism_threads` to 2 as well to see how that performs. Depending on what the actors are actually doing (e.g., are some of them idle some of the time), that may perform better. However, if they're all busy the whole time, then 1 will prevent too much contention between the actors.

Comment: Thanks for your patience. I now understand most of your answer, except that "1 will prevent too much contention between the actors`. If I've clearly set `num_cpus=1`, would there still be any contention between the actors?

Comment: Yes there can still be contention, when you specify `num_cpus=1` in the remote decorator, the Ray scheduler will make sure not to create more than one such actor per core. However, the actor could still be heavily multithreaded and could still use all of the available CPU cores. Ray does not actually prevent the actor from using all of the resources on the machine. Does that make sense?

Comment: I see. Please allow me to repeat it and see if I understand it right. If I decorate all actors with `num_cpus=1`, the maximum number of actor allowed to be created is the number of cpus specified in `ray.init`. But it does not say anything about how much cpu resources an actor are allowed to use.